# express js cannot set res.json before res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

hello im using express module in node JS

```
res.json({ auth: true, token: token, message: "success" });
res.redirect('/');
```

i have to send some json data first then redirect ..but i'm getting this error:

node:_http_outgoing:576

throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
can anyone please help, thank you

Comment: makes no sense to send a response and redirect - since a redirection would result in the browser making a request to the new url and returning the response from that ...

Comment: im using it to send a message to my custom alert which will show the user who tries to login if its username/password is correct or not.. then i have to redirect the user if its login is correct.

Comment: you could be using it for the best reasons in existence, doesn't change that you can't send a response and redirect at the same time - because, it makes no sense

Comment: so what do you recommend me to do to fix it?

Comment: If the login is correct, just redirect them.

Comment: wanted to show the success alert then redirect that's why .. thank you anyway

Comment: `wanted to show the success alert then redirect` well, the front end request wouldn't finish until after the redirect anyway ... the way to do this, since it's obvious now that the front end isn't just a form submission, there's code involved, is to change the front end to navigate to the required url (which could be returned as part of the response) after displaying the success alert - but, that's front end code

Comment: To be honest, the redirect on an AJAX request for the purposes of navigation makes absolutely no sense anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can include "redirect" as a property within json, for instance :

```
res.json({ auth: true, token: token, message: "success", redirect : "/whatever/go"});
```

then, on the client side you can perform the redirecting like this :

```
fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(body => window.location.href = body.redirect)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```